# string bound to TextBlock in ComboBox doesn't show up

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox, textblock

I have a TextBlock in a ComboBox in a C# WPF project bound to a list of 'Envelope' items, which have a string 'Name' and a double 'Weight' property, the former of which I would like to see displayed in the TextBlock.

When I run my program, the ComboBox appears without any text in it. It properly has three unlabeled items in it, and if I view the ItemsSource or SelectedItem of the ComboBox they show the appropriate values, and other code which interacts with the SelectedItem of the ComboBox behaves properly. The only thing that does not work is that the TextBlock contains no text. If I replace the `"{Binding Name}"` with `"au ghdfjlnvgmumar"` then the appropriate garbled characters appear in the ComboBox, so it is definitely a problem with the binding. What is the problem, and how can I get around it?

Relevant code:

xaml:

```
<ComboBox Name="EnvelopeList" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="200" >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

C#:

```
//main window code
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    envelopes = new List<Envelope>();
    envelopes.Add(new Envelope("TEST", 0));
    envelopes.Add(new Envelope("HI", 10));

    EnvelopeList.ItemsSource = envelopes;
}

//Envelope class
class Envelope
{
    public string Name;
    public double Weight;

    public Envelope()
    {
        Name = "[None]";
        Weight = 0;
    }
    public Envelope(string n, double w)
    {
        Name = n;
        Weight = w;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Name` is a *field*, you can only bind to [*properties*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

When `DataBinding`, you can only bind to Properties. Also, you need to update your properties with a `PropertyChangedEvent`. Otherwise, if you change your property after the initial binding it won't update the UI.

You need to use on property changed and a property

```
  public class Envelope: ModelBase 
    {
        private string _name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name= value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); }
        }

    }

    public class ModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
            }
        }
    }
```

Finally, I notice that you're setting `ItemsSource` directly. Instead, you want to set your View's `DataContext` property and then bind to your `ItemsSource`

Here is a [MSDN article on DataBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480224.aspx) that will teach you how to do it properly.